# "for" in wrong loop .js

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm having some problem with this function. I ask sorry if the code looks a bit confused.

Basically what i'm trying to do is to divide some elements between the top and bottom of the documents having between them the same space circa.

i wrote this code but seems like the first "for" cycle goes loop ever and ever again.

** update**

so i improved the code and now the problem seems to be the variable "ifc"(if-counter). It suppose to increase by one every time that one of the `if` or `else if` is completed , but as you can see on the console it always remain 0 .

anyone can help?
thanks

```
var sizewidth = window.innerWidth;
var sizeheight = 3000;

                function initialPosition(){
                    var els = document.querySelectorAll('.ico');
                    var tb = Math.round(els.length * 0.4);
                    console.log(tb); 
                    var lr = els.length - tb;
                    var distPixEachTopBottom = sizewidth / (tb/2);
                    console.log(distPixEachTopBottom);
                    var distPixEachLefRight = sizeheight / (lr/2);
                    var nextTop = 0;
                    var nextLeft = 0;
                    var nextBottom = 0;
                    var nextRight = 0 ;
                        for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
                            var ifc = 0;
                            console.log('i' + i);
                            if(i < tb){
                                var sf = 0;
                                for(;;){
                                    console.log('sf' + sf + 'tb ' + tb);
                                    if(ifc > 1){
                                        console.log('ifc'+  ifc);
                                        ifc = 0;
                                        break
                                    }else if(ifc == 0){
                                        els[i].style.top = 0 +'px';
                                        els[i].style.left = nextTop + 'px';
                                        console.log('ifc ' + ifc + 'i ' + i + 'nexttop' + nextTop)
                                        nextTop = nextTop + distPixEachTopBottom;
                                        ifc++;
                                        break;
                                    }else if(ifc == 1){
                                        els[i].style.bottom = 0 +'px';
                                        els[i].style.right = nextBottom + 'px';
                                        console.log('ifc ' + ifc + 'i ' + i + 'nextbottom' + nextBottom)
                                        nextBottom = nextBottom + distPixEachTopBottom;
                                        ifc++;
                                        break;
                                    }else{
                                        console.log('else if problem')
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                            }else{
                            }
                        }

initialPosition();
```

**update**

i created a pen as you asked

[codepen](https://codepen.io/cripava/pen/ZEOYwOx)

So basically of all the boxes the 40% of them (6 in this case) should be divided between top and bottom but they go just on top.

Comment: Can you create a pen or fiddle with HTML?

Comment: You can double check how many times the first `for` happens by doing a `console.log(i);` at the start of the loop just to see what's happening. It might be that something in the rest of your code is calling this method multiple times, causing it to look like the first `for` never stops running.

Comment: thanks guys , i added a codepen link on top as you asked

Comment: Please do not edit questions to indicate solution. Instead create an answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch i will next time, thanks

Comment: Why next time? Why not now?

Comment: @Yunnosch didn't wanted to make you lose time checking the update again, fine no problem . ill' do now

Answer (score 0):

So I solved by myself .

I put the `var ifc` before then any function .

Anyway thanks everyone